# Manually mounting /home

Tags: command-line

A week ago I turned on my Ubuntu laptop to find that when I reach the Ubuntu loading screen, I see a message which tells me that Ubuntu fails to mount the `/home` partition and that I can either skip or do a manual recovery. If I press skip, I reach the log in screen where after logging in the screen goes black and stays like that. As for manual recovery, when I select it I go into command prompt, and I don't know what to do from there.

Update: I inputted the command `df` and got the following message:

I ran `df /etc/fstab` and got the following message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNvXg.jpg

I ran the command: `more  /etc/fstab` and got the following message: `Permission denied`

I ran the command: `more /etc/fstab` and got the following message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNvXg.jpg

I ran the command 
`sudo mount  /dev/sda8  /home` and got the following message:

```
/dev/sda8 looks like swapspace - not mounted
mount: you must specify the filesytem type
```

So now what?

Do note that this is my first time on Ubuntu and on these forums so please excuse me for any foolish mistakes I have made

Update 2: I usually get an option as whether I want to boot Ubuntu or do I want advanced options for Ubuntu. I tried advanced options and booted a generic version and I received a menu giving me a number of options, such as repairing broken packages,  booting normally do checking the system. I checked the system and it said that all partitions would be mounted. After checking, I booked and it worked. However, I must boot in this way otherwise I get the same message. Anyone know why?

Comment: What happens if you choose manual recovery? Do you get to a command prompt? If so, edit your question and add the output of `df` as well as the contents of `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Jos I would like to know how will I figure out what are the contents if /etc/fstab  ?       Unfortunately I am nothe very experienced with command prompt

Comment: The command is `more /etc/fstab`.

Comment: After inputting the command, I get the following:            / was on /dev/stay during installation                  /boot/efi as on /dev/sda2 during installation        /home was on dev/sda8/ during installation              What do I do now?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of your command, as well as the output of `df`. Also try `sudo mount /dev/sda8 /home`. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I get the error message /dev/sda8 looks like swapspace - not mounted     mount: you must specify the filesystem type.     P.S. I am sorry about editing,  the output I received is too large for me to post and I am trying to post a picture but I do not have enough repuation

Comment: Then post your output to something like pastebin.com or imgur.com and add the link to the question. These comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `sudo blkid` and `sudo cat /etc/fstab`, `sudo fdisk -l`, and `sudo lsblk`, and then boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, start `gparted`, and take a screenshot of /sda.

Comment: please share the result of `sudo cat /etc/fstab` and also try to mount `sda6` as `/home` ( not `sda8`)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. You can copy that text and [edit] your question to show us that text.

Comment: @guntbert OP can't copy/paste text from a system that won't boot properly to their own account. Maybe... if they log into a minimal root... but then the network may not work...

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

**I still need the `terminal` output of:**

```
sudo blkid
sudo cat /etc/fstab
sudo fdisk -l
sudo lsblk

*screenshot of gparted /dev/sda
```

**To check the file system on your Ubuntu partitions...**

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda5`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda6`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`